# tornado.web : Is there a method which is called after the actual handler method?

Tags: python, tornado

Tornado web framework seems to expose a method RequestHandler.prepare() which is called before the actual handler method. I was wondering if there's a similar method which is called after the handler ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting Tornado 2.2 now you can override RequestHandler.on_finish for post-request processing.

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite `RequestHandler.finish`: [see docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/web.html?highlight=prepare#tornado.web.RequestHandler.finish) and [source code](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/_modules/tornado/web.html#RequestHandler.finish).

Comment: RequestHandler.finish seems to have a lot of boiler plate code that i'll need to replicate if i override it. I was thinking of introducing another method RequestHandler.Cleanup and then calling it within RequestHandler._execute() after the request is handled. Then any of my handlers can override the cleanup method just like the prepare() method. What do you think ? Only thing, I'm not sure if all the requests are handled via _execute in all conditions or not?

Comment: I'm not sure if all the requests are handled via `_execute`. But the way to propose requires you to touch `tornado`'s source code. I was suggesting, instead, to define a `finish` method in your handler that does something and then calls `RequestHandler`'s `finish`.

Comment: @newbie, You can always just fork Tornado on Github, add your cleanup method, make a pull request, and start the conversation with the maintainers/developers there...